# Can object in a compound sentence be ommited in order to avoid repetition?

Tags: grammar

ナイフでお肉を切ります、それからフォークで(お肉を)食べます。

Cut the meat with a knife, then eat the meat with a fork.

I wondered whether the second (お肉を) could be omitted in order to avoid repetition. Is it totally acceptable in grammar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can omit 2nd appearance of お肉。

Here is one another way to put it.
お肉をナイフで切ってフォークで食べます。
In this you can connect 2 sentences by verb's て form.

Just like we would say in English "Cut the meat by knife and eat by fork." no need of 2nd occurrence of object as its already implied.

Comment: Did you intend to change the verb when you added the て form?

Comment: I don't get your question clearly. You mean different verb or something else ?

Comment: In your version, you have 切れて, which is the て form of the intransitive verb 切れる. The OP's question has the transitive verb 切る, the て form of which is 切って.

Comment: thanks changed now.